# How to configure opendj subtree replication

Tags: ldap, openldap, opendj

I have an opendj dc=example,dc=com, now I want to copy ou=People,dc=example,dc=com to another empty opendj (only copy the data of ou=People), how can I do it.
Do I need to set the second opendj base to ou=People,dc=example,dc=com, I tried many times and failed, can anyone help me, my opendj version is 4.5.4

I try to set up replication using ./dsreplication, but the system keeps prompting Basedn error. Please forgive me, because the information is confidential, I can't send out my screenshot

Comment: Do you want a replicated copy (i.e. maintained replicated over time), or do you just need a copy a some point?

Comment: I need a copy, and keep replicating over time

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ replication can be configured to replicated only a subtree (ou=People,dc=example,dc=com) if and only if the subtree is contained in its own backend.
If the whole tree of data for dc=example,dc=com is stored in a single backend, you cannot replicated a just a subtree.